# How should I ask for more details on an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

I really just want to follow up with the poster of this question

[silverlight TypeDescriptor.GetConverter substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962780/silverlight-typedescriptor-getconverter-substitute)

to get more details on how he implemented the fix. Specifically if he can post the code he modified in LINQ to CSV project to make it work in Silverlight. I have tried to interpret the accepted answer with no luck.

Comment: Leave a comment if you're allowed to. If that's not yet the case (insufficient rep for example, which seems to be your problem) then first get the rep.

Comment: Ok - im new to stack overflow so basically you are saying that first i need to ask and answer questions to gain enought rep to be able to simplly get clarification on the problem i am trying to solve today?

Comment: The "question" you linked to is an answer. Is your link wrong, or did you mean to write "answer"?

Comment: @user1640825 Yep, that's what I'm saying. Unless, as Mark suggests below, you can ask a good original question related to your problem, which will not be seen as a duplicate of the question you point to. Commenting is a privilege you will need to gain. You don't get it from the start. (P.s. it's only 50 rep, which isn't all that much)

Comment: Probably my link was wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962780/silverlight-typedescriptor-getconverter-substitute i really just want more details on the accepted answer and specifically how it was implemented in the context of the existing LINQ to CSV project.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses. I'll work on gaining some rep so i can leave a comment. I'll also craft a new question, since the original is a year old maybe some new eyes will help me solve the problem of using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library in Silverlight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of three approaches you could use:

1. Leave a comment to the original poster. If you are lucky he will see it and update the answer. It might take a while though, and he may be too busy to reply.
2. Post a new question linking to the existing one and asking for more detailed information about your specific problem. Show what you've tried and what error you got. This allows anyone to help you, not just the original poster.
3. Leave a bounty on the original question to increase attention and encourage better answers that include the information you need.

You might find that option 2 gets you the specific answer you want the fastest.

Comment: Correct general answer. Just of note for the OP: As of yet 1 and 3 are not available to you. You will need a sufficient amount of rep for both those.